# Uniquely assign a token to device + browser in NextJs with SSR

Tags: next.js, redis, token, server-side-rendering

I am working with a NextJs application where I call an API on server side with an API generated token. The requirement here is to keep this token unique to device and browser through which the request has been made.

Below are a few things to be taken care of -

- API call is being made on server side with an API generated token that expires in a few hours
- Token should not be stored on client side
- Redis can be used to store the token with a key (i.e. a key unique to device + browser )
- Using user-agent as key doesn't 100% assure the key would be unique

**Any help or lead would be much appreciated!!**